# DOM based routing or MPA implementation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Trying to find resources on how to set things up with the (as of 2023) somewhat current level of tool stack which for us means Vue 3, Tailwind and Prime Vue.

We currently run a Optimizely CMS 11 site (.NET Framework 4.7.2) where the routing is based on the pages created in Optimizely. On top of this we have a Vue 2 framework that runs in a [DOM based routing](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/) context where different apps are mounted based on class names on the body along with some common apps that are used on the whole site. All of this is compiled (webpack) to a few js file; main.js and vendor.js for caching purposes due to the page reload mechanism of the "regular" page routing mechanism.

Loading of an app looks somewhat like this for reference:

```
import App1 from "../apps/app1";
import mountApp from "../utils/mount-app";

export default {
  init() {
    this.modifyDOM();
  },

  modifyDOM() {
    mountApp({
      app: App1,
      selector: '[data-app=app1]',
      props: {
        pageName: window.document.title,
      },
    });
  },
};
```

And the mountApp logic looks like this:

```
export default ({ app, selector, props = {}, extractProps = () => ({}) }) => {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  const mounted = [];

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, el => {
    const appProps = {
      ...props,
      ...extractProps(el),
    };

    const PropsApp = app(appProps);
    mounted.push(new PropsApp().$mount(el));
  });

  return mounted;
}
```

I know that most things nowadays are SPA's (and Optimizely has great headless/SPA support) but is there any similar, more up-to-date approach of this, where we still can rely on Optimizely/.NET for the general routing and loading of pages and have different apps and modules loaded on different pages? And perhaps ditch webpack for more current tools like Vite or similar?

Our aim is to create a base common tooling setup that can be used for both this kind of setup but also for SPA's since we use that approach more commonly on interal applications where the focus of the app is more specific and not so wide as it is on our website.